# How to set player for course lesson in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, rxjs

I have course details component. In this component I have 2 child component, for player and for lessons. Now when I click on one of the lesson it need to load in player the suitable video. Can any one help me with some ideas how can I do this ? How we can in Angular on click from one component send commands to other component ?
[image]

this is parent component

```
<div class='course-details'>
  <div>
     <app-course-player [course]='course'></app-course-player>
  </div>
 <div>
    <app-lesson-card class='w-full' [course]='course'></app-lesson-card>
</div>
</div>
```

player component

```
<div *ngFor='let courseLesson of course.lessons'>
<vg-player class='w-full  video-size'>
    <vg-overlay-play vgFor='dreamclass-video'></vg-overlay-play>
    <vg-controls>
        <vg-play-pause></vg-play-pause>
        <vg-playback-button></vg-playback-button>
        <vg-scrub-bar>
            <vg-scrub-bar-current-time></vg-scrub-bar-current-time>
            <vg-scrub-bar-buffering-time></vg-scrub-bar-buffering-time>
        </vg-scrub-bar>
        <vg-time-display vgProperty='left' vgFormat='mm:ss'></vg-time-display>
        <vg-mute></vg-mute>
        <vg-fullscreen></vg-fullscreen>
    </vg-controls>
    <video #myMedia
           [vgMedia]='myMedia'
           [poster]='"img-proxy/plain/" + courseLesson.coverUrl'
           id='dreamclass-video'
           [src]='courseLesson.videoUrl'>
    </video>
</vg-player>
</div>

get data from here
 @Input() course: ICourse;
```

lesson component

```
   <div class='course-section w-full lg:w-auto border border-white-gray mt-4 lg:mt-0'>
      <div class='flex items-center justify-between'>
           <p class='text-primary   text-2xl price-box font-medium'>Free</p>
      </div>
        <div class='theme-section border-t border-b border-white-gray'>
                <div class='flex items-center justify-between top-margin' *ngFor='let lessonData of course.lessons'>
                    <div class='flex items-center'>
                        <img src='assets/images/sliders/lock.svg' class='mr-right' alt=''>
                        <p class='text-sm font-normal text-darkgray course-box-title'>{{lessonData.title}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div><p
                        class='text-sm font-normal text-regulargray'>{{lessonData.duration * 1000 | date: 'mm:ss'}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div>
                <button *ngIf='!course?.enrolled' mat-raised-button class='enrol-butn' color='primary'
                        (click)='enrollCourse()'> Enroll
                </button>
                <button *ngIf='course?.enrolled' mat-raised-button class='enrol-butn text-white' color='accent'
                        (click)='enrollCourse()'> Enrolled
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: To avoid Down Votes on your question, I would change the title for something more specific to the Angular framework. Ex: "How to change a component state when another component changes?"

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using a **service**.

1. Create a service:

```
ng g s MyServiceName --skip-Tests
```

Once it is created, check that has been decorated as providedIn root:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyServiceNameService {
....
```

2. In your service, declare all you want the components have in commun.
   e.g:

```
private _courseSelected: ICourse
```

3. Inject the service in the constructor of your components (in course-player and in lesson-card):

```
...
import { MyServiceNameService } from '../../services/my-service-name.service';
...
constructor(
   private myServiceNameService : MyServiceNameService ) {
  }
...
```

4. Used directly the variables in the service from your components, or better, make methods in the service to modify the varaibles values.

e.g:

in service:

```
...
export class MyServiceNameService {
public get courseSelected() {
   return this._courseSelected;
}
constructor(){}
public someFunctionThaCausesTheVideoSelectionChanges(newVideoUrl: string){
this._courseSelected = newVideoUrl;
}
...
```

in component:

```
const myCourseSelectede = this.myServiceNameService.courseSelected;

....
setNewCourse ( newCourse: string) {
   this.myServiceNameService.someFunctionThaCausesTheVideoSelectionChanges(newCourse);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using an Output event in the lesson-card component and using template ids in the parent component.

Something like:

```
<div class='course-details'>
 <div>
     <app-course-player #player [course]='course'></app-course-player>
 </div>
 <div>
    <app-lesson-card class='w-full' (videoSelect)="player.play($event)" [course]='course'></app-lesson-card>
 </div>
</div>
```

In the lesson-card component declare the Output Event:

```
export class LessonCardComponent {
  @Output()videoSelect = new EventEmitter<string>('');
  ...
  someFunctionThaCausesTheVideoSelectionChanges(){
     videoSelect.emit('new video url');
  }
}
```

In the course-player component, declare the play function

```
export class CoursePlayerComponent{
   ...
   play(videoUrl: string){
      ...
   }
}
```